# Full page background image

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to achieve a fullpage background image. How I can I get this background image to take up the height of the page without it having to scroll?

http://jsfiddle.net/DFN5y/

```css
#cover {
 background: url(http://bootstrapguru.com/preview/cascade/images/carousel/imageOne.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 background-size: cover;
 height:100%;
}
```

At the moment the 100% plus the fixed height makes it too tall.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/DFN5y/2/

Comment: I think so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your `#cover` a fixed position and fluid dimensions:

```
#cover {
    background: url(http://bootstrapguru.com/preview/cascade/images/carousel/imageOne.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DFN5y/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can style for body to do tha:

```
body {
  background: url(http://bootstrapguru.com/preview/cascade/images/carousel/imageOne.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 background-size: cover;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DFN5y/1/)**

**Update:** without styling body

```
 #cover {
   background: url(http://bootstrapguru.com/preview/cascade/images/carousel/imageOne.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   background-size: cover;
   height:100%;
   position:fixed;
   width: 100%;
   }
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DFN5y/3/)**

Comment: The issue with using body is that i am using a template system and I need the body to be the same in each template, sorry I should have mentioned that

Comment: @Jimmy:Updated the answer. check now